# In Git, how to merge (not checkout) part of files from a long ago branch

Tags: git, merge

Like **Fig.A**, `release-1.0` is delivered to customer long long ago, but a huge bug was found recently, and a hotfix is made in `release-1.1` and re-delivered.

Now I would like to merge **only bugfix files** (about 10 files) from `release-1.1` into branch `master` in `Fig.B` way, that is, `release-1.1` **must** be a parent-node of `master` in git history. So `git checkout release-1.1 <file>` way does not match this purpose.

Meanwhile, since `c2` is so far from `master`, there are too many different files (nearly hundreds files that can not merge automatically), and the work of canceling these merge conflicts may kill me....

So how could I realize this purpose in git? Sorry for my poor English and poor git skills. ^_^

Fig A:

```
    release-1.0 <--- release-1.1                          
        |                                                              
        v                                                           
c1 <--- c2 <--- c3 <--- c4 <--- c5 <--- c6 <--- master
```

Fig B:

```
    release-1.0 <--- release-1.1 <----------------------\
        |                                               |       
        v                                               |       
c1 <--- c2 <--- c3 <--- c4 <--- c5 <--- c6 <--- c7 <--- master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way around dealing with potential merge conflicts, because the hotfix was made on a much older version of the branch.

One option would be to cherry-pick the hotfix commit, and then choose the version of the files from the latest `master` branch for all files *except* for the 10 files involved in the hotfix:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 release-1.1>
```

where `<SHA-1 release 1.1>` is the SHA-1 hash of the hotfix commit in the `release-1.1` branch.  Keep in mind you may get conflicts in the 10 hotfix files themselves.  In this case, you should focus on the hotfix changes, tending to choose the latest `master` version in all other cases.

Comment: many thanks, and I finally found the way with your help: 1. `git merge -s ours <release-1.1>` to make **a fake merge which only treat `release-1.1` as parent node of new merge-commit master**  2. `git cherry-pick --no-commit <release-1.1>` to **pick files modified from `release-1.1` into index and working-dir of current master** 3. `git commit --amend` to **put the selected files into merge-commit of master**